# Is it possible to execute a script that takes user input then execute another script

Tags: shell-script, vpn, remote-desktop

I am trying to run:

1. Script1: takes password to start VPN
2. Script2: Script1 must be started (but not ended). Launches remote desktop

Is it possible to run both of those with one command? Every time I try `Script1 &` it errors out, but works fine if I run `Script1`. I cant do `Script1 && Script2` because Script1 hasnt finished when Script2 needs to start.

Script1:

```
VPNUSER=Rilcon42
VPNGRP=01
# =============================================================================

    # you shouldn't have to change anything below here
    VPNURL=https://remote.someserver.edu
    VPNSCRIPT=/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script

    sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun1 && \
    sudo ifconfig tun1 up && \
    sudo /usr/sbin/openconnect -s $VPNSCRIPT $VPNURL --user=$VPNUSER --authgroup=$VPNGRP --interface=tun1

    sudo ifconfig tun1 down
```

Script2:

```
rdesktop 123.1234.23.1453
```

Comment: Try fabric if possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script1+2:

```
VPNUSER=Rilcon42
VPNGRP=01
# =============================================================================

    # you shouldn't have to change anything below here
    VPNURL=https://remote.someserver.edu
    VPNSCRIPT=/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script

    sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun1 && \
    sudo ifconfig tun1 up && \
    sudo /usr/sbin/openconnect -s $VPNSCRIPT $VPNURL --user=$VPNUSER --authgroup=$VPNGRP --interface=tun1 &

    rdesktop 123.1234.23.1453
    wait

    sudo ifconfig tun1 down
```

Comment: There is a `&` at the end of openconnect command, so rdesktop will instantly run after openconnect.

Comment: I needed to add `/bin/echo $PASSWD |` before `sudo /usr/sbin/openconnect...` in order to input a password correctly (stored as a variable-- bad practice), but this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The part that reads user input from the terminal needs to run in the foreground. In most setups, `sudo` needs to run in the foreground.

Call `sudo` on the whole script. Calling `sudo` separately like this to run successive commands doesn't make much sense.

Assuming that `openconnect` doesn't read user input, change `Script` to

```
VPNUSER=Rilcon42
VPNGRP=01
VPNURL=https://remote.someserver.edu
VPNSCRIPT=/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script

sudo -b sh -c '
  openvpn --mktun --dev tun1 &&
  ifconfig tun1 up && {
    /usr/sbin/openconnect -s "$1" "$2" --user="$3" --authgroup="$4" --interface=tun1
    ifconfig tun1 down
  }
' "$VPNSCRIPT" "$VPNURL" "$VPNUSER" "$VPNGRP"
```

and run Script1 in the foreground, but only after the VPN is connected (which may be annoying to detect — maybe by pinging the remote end until it comes up).

I'm not familiar with openconnect so I'm guessing what it does. If `openconnect` requires user input from the terminal and then blocks until the VPN is disconnected, then running it in the background won't work. But if that's the way it works, it probably has an option to go into the background after reading the password.

Comment: Not sure why but this version of `Script1` didnt work after I pasted it into a new file and ran it.